# Screen brightness changing randomly every 2-3 seconds

Tags: 18.04, updates, screen, brightness

I have an issue with the brightness of my screen since I've done the 18.04 update.
Basically the luminosity of the screen changes every 2 or 3 seconds which is very exhausting for the eyes.

I've tried to look at other chats if people were facing something similar but couldn't find anything reflecting my case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this happen on a laptop? Is it sudden?

Comment: Yes it happens on a laptop and is completely sudden

Comment: Is settings > Power > Automatic brightness On?

Comment: I just don't have this automatic brightness option, I cannot find it

Comment: I've found it thank you! However isn't it strange that this automatic adjustment doesn't work properly?

Comment: @Unidi Please click the check mark next to the answer below. As far as "strange" goes not really you have unique hardware and/or setup that hasn't been tested yet.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off `settings > Power > Automatic brightness`